# Poweroff via ssh with a nohup

Tags: ssh, nohup

I have a qemu virtual machine. I want to cleanly power it off using SSH (I want to use it for a systemd service).

Currently I did

```
ssh vm /sbin/poweroff
```

This works, but `ssh` return a 255 error code.

I tried

```
ssh vm 'nohup /sbin/poweroff &'
```

But then the machine doesn't power off. Why?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like ssh is having problems with the background process causing it to hang, so ssh aggressively ends the session (that's a WAG). I don't know the specifics of what is going on, but I suspect the reason you get 255 returned is ssh is avoiding getting into a hung state. See here for a bit more info: [Wikipedia - NoHup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup#Overcoming_hanging)

The article goes on to discuss using a multiplexer, which is what I commonly do.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that the system I run inside qemu, Minix, has no job control. I guess this may be the reason...